FGSM for logistic regression
In arXiv:1412.6572 (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6572, a seminal article), it is stated that
$$\mathrm{sgn}(\nabla_{\mathbf{x}} L(\mathbf{x},y,\mathbf{w})) = -\mathrm{sgn}(\mathbf{w})$$
for the softplus loss function $$L(\mathbf{x},y,\mathbf{w}) = \mathbb{E}_{(\mathbf{x},y)\sim p_{\rm data}}\log(1 + e^{-y(\mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{x}+b)}).$$
I am not able to reproduce the result. What I get is
$$\mathrm{sgn}(\nabla_{\mathbf{x}} L(\mathbf{x},y,\mathbf{w})) = -\mathrm{sgn}(\mathbb{E}_{(\mathbf{x},y)\sim p_{\rm data}} y)\mathrm{sgn}( \mathbf{w}).$$
I can't see how the first term goes away. Am I missing something?

If $L$ is an expectation w.r.t.  the inputs to the model $\bf x$ and targets $y \in {-1,1}$ what is the meaning of the gradient $\nabla_{\bf x} L$ w.r.t. the inputs? $\mathbb{E}{(\mathbf{x},y)\sim p{\rm data}}$ is just $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N$ over all the inputs ${\bf x}_i$ and labels $y_i$.
